# Is it possible to <jsp:include> a page using its full path name?

Tags: jsp, include

Is something like `<jsp:include page="C:/Documents and Settings/admin/My Documentslibrary/example.jsp"></jsp:include>` possible? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try it? Shouldn't the exposed behaviour be an obvious answer?

Comment: @BalusC It obviously didn't work. I just wanted to if it was possible in anyway or if I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. jsp:include can have relative path or expressions. It cannot contain a protocol name, port number, or domain name. The URL can be absolute or relative to the current JSP page. If it is absolute (beginning with a /), the pathname is resolved by your web or application server.